# How to get files names in multiple folders under some condition

Tags: c#, string, linq, file, directory

If I have a path like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\basic\data\
```

and in this path folders like this :

```
20160314_002_874
20160314_004_657
20160314_006_169
20160315_006_169
20160316_006_169
```

---

How to get all files names in these folders where the date part of these folders names = specific date

Ex :
I want all files names in folders which name begin with the following date(`20160314`)in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DirectoryInfo`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();
DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\basic\data\");
var directories = rootDir.GetDirectories("20160314*");
foreach (var directory in directories)
{
    files.AddRange(directory.GetFiles());
}

IEnumerable<string> fileNames = files.Select(f => f.Name);
```

use `IEnumerable<string> fileNames = files.Select(f => f.FullName);` to get the file name with path.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(myPath).Where(x => x.StartsWith(20160314));
 dirs.ForEach(xx => {
     var fullPath = Path.Combine(myPath, xx);
     var files = Directory.GetFiles(fullPath);
     //Files is a string[], do whatever you want
 });
```

And you will get all subdirectories that match with this date: `20160314`. After that you can get the files by Combine the original path with the directory name and using `GetFiles(string path)` to get the filename list.

Comment: It's not mine as you can see. Flag and report to moderator